# Galaxy S6 no longer automatically connects to my home WIFI

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-6

Vexing problem. I changed Internet service providers at home. It works fine.  However, my Galaxy S6 used to automatically connect to my wifi whenever I got home and now it doesn't. I have to tap the WIFI icon manually.  I changed none of my settings. Only the wifi changed.  I've looked in the settings and can't figure it out.  Help?

Comment: What is different about your new Wi-Fi router?

Comment: dunno. different ISP. different wifi.

Comment: Is it the same old router or a new router?

Comment: New router. I mean, it works fine. We can all hook up to it. but by phone is no longer AUTOMATICALLY going to my wifi when I'm home

Comment: Have you tried going to the list of wifis available, finding your network, then clicking forget. Once it's forgotten, reboot your phone. Connect to your wifi again and see if that fixed the problem? Once you reconnect, you can turn off your wifi, wait a few seconds, then turn it back on to see if it automatically reconnects to the network.

Comment: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/108614/att-samsung-galaxy-s6-will-not-connect-to-wifi-automatically