# Galaxy S6 and S7 not auto-connecting to WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I've had a problem with my phones  (Galaxy S6 and S7) not auto-connecting to WiFi. When I open up the WiFi settings it will connect.

Is there any way I can determine if an app is disrupting the ability to auto-connect?

I think it is not the phone because I just got a new S7.

I think it is not the router because this happens with multiple routers.

Thanks very much for your help.

Edit: This is close to being a duplicate of
[AT&T Samsung Galaxy S6 will not connect to WiFi automatically](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/108614/171981) and
[Galaxy S6 no longer automatically connects to my home WIFI](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/145590/171981)

Edit 2: I have uninstalled a bunch of apps on my S6 and it now auto-connects without issue!

Edit 3: I have uninstalled a bunch of apps on my S7 and it now auto-connects without issue!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with app interference. I have uninstalled a bunch of apps on my phones and they now auto-connect without issue.

I wish I knew which app or apps was the culprit. As I install back some apps that I need maybe I will find out. If I do I will update this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Had the same problem with ATT S7. Spun my wheels trying to figure out. Samsung tech a BestBuy finally fixed it. He said there's a bug with ATT auto connect app. I think it was called something like WiFi Direct.... anyway we removed all ATT apps on the phone that we were allowed to remove. That fixed the issue. Now it connects to all WiFi previously connected to.

Answer (score 1):

I've been having the same problem for a couple months, just finished a chat session with Samsung.  I was advised to restart my phone in **SAFE MODE** and then manually delete and re-add my home WIFI network (ORBI mesh).  Restarted the phone and tested by walking outside far enough from home to disconnect from WIFI.  Upon returning within range, Galaxy S6 reconnected fine!  Have only done this one test, will report back if anything changes.

Answer (score 0):

I had exactly this problem with my Galaxy S6 international phone -- no matter what I tried in the system settings, it wasn't resolved.  Then I came across this:

https://thedroidguy.com/2018/10/fix-samsung-galaxy-s6-can-no-longer-connect-wi-fi-mobile-data-networks-troubleshooting-guide-1068247#Problem2

Immediately the issue was resolved!  Also importantly, I didn't notice any collateral damage / undesired change with clearing the system cache.

Edit: Unfortunately the issue came back for me :(  Note though I have an international 920F phone.  My search continues...