# Galaxy S6 (international ver) not auto-connecting to WiFi

Tags: wi-fi, samsung-galaxy-s-6

I have a Galaxy S6 SM-G920F that will not auto-connect to WiFi starting several weeks ago.  This appears similar to what is mentioned in [Galaxy S6 and S7 not auto-connecting to WiFi](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/149008/galaxy-s6-and-s7-not-auto-connecting-to-wifi) except I don't have an AT&T phone and that mentions uninstalling some AT&T apps.

It doesn't matter what WiFi hotspot it is, it won't (*Edit: rarely does*) auto reconnect.  If I click on the WiFi icon then click the hotspot name, it will connect.

Here are things I tried:

1. Forget a hotspot then re-login with password
2. Reboot the phone
3. Toggle the "Smart network switch" and "Hotspot 2.0" advanced options
4. Clear the system cache as described in https://thedroidguy.com/2018/10/fix-samsung-galaxy-s6-can-no-longer-connect-wi-fi-mobile-data-networks-troubleshooting-guide-1068247#Problem2

*Edit*: I noticed today that it auto-connected once.  Also a couple days ago, I saw that once when I tried manually connecting, the status went back to Connecting.. then when back out, then went to Connecting.. then said it was Connected with no internet, then a few moments later it resolved itself and became Connected.

What else can I try, besides a factory reset?  Has anyone else seen this issue on a SM-G920F model?